# How to ignore assembly load fail in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I have a project that reference to two hardware dlls which refers to two sdk of different version and will select which hardware library to use based on the hardware detected. However, for some of our older clients, to install the sdk of the later hardware requires upgrading to windows 8, which is not an option for them.

```
               /---------Hardware1Wrapper-------Hardware1SDKLibraries
Main Program --
               \---------Hardware2Wrapper-------Hardware2SDKLibraries(Win8)
```

This causes the the program to be not able to resolve one of the dlls and crashes.

Is there a way that I can ignore the "Could not load file or assembly" error knowing that in runtime I'll never get to that code? Something similar to resolution:=optional in OSGI?

Comment: If you don't have the source code and cannot fix it correctly, then the only option you have is to use a local or machine redirect.

Comment: @JohnPeters any url reference to the options you were mentioning? Many thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "I'll never get to that code" but can you not build an interface in a separate project with all the common methods of both libraries then create 2 separate projects where each references the interface you've created and each referencing the relevant sdk library. In your main app, use Assembly.Load to load the relevant one based on the OS. We use this and works very well.

Comment: If you do allow Instantiating Hardware1Wrapper/Hardware2Wrapper on basis of OS, It will ensure that only relevant assembly get loaded.(Assuming you are not referencing any other type from those assembalies)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=machine+redirect&oq=machine+redirect&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2715j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8